# How to change an ID depending on the color of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn javascript on my own, so I'm lacking a lot. I'm trying to change the color of multiples elements depending on the color in the css of another element.

I want the javascript to detect the `<div id>` with a specific color, and then change the id of another `<div id2>`

I tried this :

```js
if (document.getElementById("name").css('color') == "#7a5cd4") {

  document.getElementById('border').setAttribute('id', 'red');
  document.getElementById('line').setAttribute('id', 'linered');

}
```

```css
#name {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #7a5cd4;
}

#border {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%
}

#red {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%
}

#line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

#linered {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="name">name</div>

  <div id="border"></div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is a function that takes an element as a parameter and returns an object containing all of the styles that are being used on that object. We can then call `getPropertyValue` on the result to get the value of a css property.

These functions return colours in the form `rgb(r, g, b)`, so we will need to compare the value to `rgb(122, 92, 212)`, instead of `#7a5cd4`.

[`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), however, would not work in your case as it only gets the inline style, which is when you specify the style in your html, like `<div style="color: red">`.

Also, it is recommended to use classes for selecting elements, instead of ids, as you can place multiple of them on the same element.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('name');
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

if (styles.getPropertyValue('color') == 'rgb(122, 92, 212)') {

  document.getElementById('border').setAttribute('id', 'red');
  document.getElementById('line').setAttribute('id', 'linered');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the id of element you:

```
document.getElementById('oldid').id = 'newid'
```

**This rest of this answer fit to inline style (element style="color: value") while @BenjaminDavies answer fit more to your original question:**

In order to check/change color property you:

```
var divOldColor = document.getElementById('oldid').style.color; // get the color to variable
if (divOldColor == '#7a5cd4') { // do something }
```

Put it all together we get something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('name').style.color == '#7a5cd4') {
  document.getElementById('border').id = 'red';
  document.getElementById('line').id = 'linered';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` is not a vanilla JS function. Use `.style.cssPropertyName` instead.

```
if (document.getElementById("name").style.color === "#7a5cd4") {

  document.getElementById('border').setAttribute('id', 'red');
  document.getElementById('line').setAttribute('id', 'linered');

}
```